# Testing for IE8 and IE7 using IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

Can anyone comment on the accuracy of the IE7 and IE8 modes when usinf IE9?
http://lifeonubuntu.com/how-to-test-ie9-ie8-and-ie7-from-the-same-computer/

Answer (score 4):

Swapping out your Browser Mode is very reliable in testing various versions of IE. Granted, you're not actually running in IE7 when you tell IE10 to Emulate IE7, but you probably won't find many differences between the two.

I use this many times a day to test various different websites, with a great deal of accuracy. For further reading, I'd encourage you to check out [Testing sites with Browser Mode vs. Doc Mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/19/testing-sites-with-browser-mode-vs-doc-mode.aspx).

Comment: Casting my +1 vote. "IE6 accounts for less than 1% of total traffic" taken from http://cssgrid.net/. Google Analytics also reports a wide majority of heavy IE users coming from IE8+ as we are also rapidly seeing people update their browsers in Windows on a large scale.

Comment: i've found it doesn't always work..mostly, but some bugs are not showing on the fake browser mode..

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to test my sites in IE7, IE8, IE9 in parallel using separate Virtual Machines on OS X.  [This blog post](http://www.markomedia.com.au/ie6-ie7-ie8-ie9/) explains how to do this, it's quite simple.